# HighCharts showing two different instances of same chart on different PCs

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts, data-visualization

We are running into a very strange problem where the same chart rendering 1st. data point on series differently on different PCs. On some PCs 1st series value is missing totally and not showing up while on some PCs it correct. We have checked for Browser Cache, Server Cache, Browsers Versions, OS, Location, etc. but the problem is still there. Two PCs in same building showing the same chart differently.

Comment: Hi @Sheryl, That issue is possibly related to the data grouping feature: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping Please try to disable it through options: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, I already tried disabling data grouping but no luck. Any other clue? Also, why the behavior is inconsistent... I mean some PCs are showing data correctly while some aren't. If it was data grouping issue then wasn't it was supposed to be same across all devices!

Comment: It may depend on the width of the screen. At different widths, the data may be grouped differently. It would be best if you provide your chart options and data. You can reproduce your chart in jsfiddle, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: @ppotaczek Thanks for your reply... Please message me directly if you can. I don't see a way to message you directly!

Comment: @ppotaczek Thanks for your suggestions... We were able to fix the issue ourselves